# How do I change the stacking order in a bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From the [online bar chart guide](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/geom_bar.html):

```
qplot(factor(cyl), data=mtcars, geom="bar", fill=factor(gear))
```

[image: barplot using <code>qplot</code> feature of <code>ggplot2</code>]

How do I get 5 to sit on the bottom, 4 above that, and 3 on top?

Comment: that's totally unfriendly for color-blind people! :-)

Comment: Is there any color scheme specialized for those users? It'd be nice...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qplot(factor(cyl), data=mtcars, geom="bar", fill=factor(gear), order = -gear)`

Comment: This gives `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'gear' not found`

Answer (score 5):

```
qplot(factor(cyl), data=mtcars, geom='bar', fill=factor(gear, level=5:3))
```

Comment: You got it, but it's more convenient to define new `data.frame` and then run `qplot` on `transform()` ed one, hence getting clean legend and axis: `newone <- transform(mtcars, cyl = factor(cyl), gear = factor(gear, levels = 5:3))` Then: `qplot(cyl, data = newone, fill = gear)`... and the code is cleaner too!

Answer (score 1):

To generalize @xiechao's solution (@hadley's doesn't work in latest ggplot), you can reverse the factor orders to achieve this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)  # First make factor with default levels
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear, levels=rev(levels(mtcars$gear)))
qplot(cyl, data=mtcars, geom="bar", fill=gear)
# Or with ggplot
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), fill=gear)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]