# How to order values on a dotplot produced via qplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I generated this with `qplot(log10(InDegree), username , data = df, colour = insamples)`.

Is there a way I tell qplot to order the dots from lower to higher value on the y-axis?
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the stacking order in a bar chart in ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427742/how-do-i-change-the-stacking-order-in-a-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Comment: It seems like a different question to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key step is to create a factor of the names with codes in the order of the values.

```
require(datasets); require(ggplot2)
precip2 = precip[-50]; precip2 = precip2[order(precip2)][1:20]
states = names(precip2); states = factor(states, levels=states)
qplot(precip2, states, data = d)
```

[image]

Comment: Or more easily, use `reorder`